# Where can I get labels for small ImageNet?

Tags: dataset, image-classification

I have recently downloaded the small image net dataset:

http://image-net.org/small/download.php

The archives contain a lot of images, but no other files. How do I know which label the images have?

Answer (score 3):

I am affraid this dataset does not include labels,

You can use datasets that are described here:

https://patrykchrabaszcz.github.io/Imagenet32/

Those files will have the same format as CIFAR dataset

And they will contain labels according to the map file that is available in original Imagenet devkit.

Answer (score 1):

The labels for small ImageNet dataset are provided in the same manner as the labels for the original (large) dataset. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40744700/how-can-i-find-imagenet-data-labels